# How to remove authentication from HTTPServerAuthModule in Jboss EAP

Tags: java, authentication, jboss6.x

I need to create a custom auth module similar to HTTPBasicServerAuthModule that should not prompt for username and password for authentication. Because, we have a jwt token that will take care of authentication for us, and we do not need another layer of authentication. Following is my custom auth module:

```
public class CustomJaspiAuthModule extends WebServerAuthModule
{
    protected Context context;
    protected boolean cache = false;
    public static final byte[] AUTHENTICATE_BYTES = {
        (byte) 'W',
        (byte) 'W',
        (byte) 'W',
        (byte) '-',
        (byte) 'A',
        (byte) 'u',
        (byte) 't',
        (byte) 'h',
        (byte) 'e',
        (byte) 'n',
        (byte) 't',
        (byte) 'i',
        (byte) 'c',
        (byte) 'a',
        (byte) 't',
        (byte) 'e'
    };
    protected String delegatingLoginContextName = null;

    public CustomJaspiAuthModule() { }

    public CustomJaspiAuthModule(String delegatingLoginContextName) {
        super();
        this.delegatingLoginContextName = delegatingLoginContextName;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthStatus secureResponse(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException {
        // do nothing, just return SUCCESS.
        return AuthStatus.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject clientSubject, Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException {
        Request request = (Request) messageInfo.getRequestMessage();
        Response response = (Response) messageInfo.getResponseMessage();

        Principal principal;
        context = request.getContext();
        LoginConfig config = context.getLoginConfig();

        // validate any credentials already included with this request.
        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        MessageBytes authorization = request.getCoyoteRequest().getMimeHeaders().getValue("authorization");

        if (authorization != null) {
            authorization.toBytes();
            ByteChunk authorizationBC = authorization.getByteChunk();

            if (authorizationBC.startsWithIgnoreCase("basic ", 0)) {
                authorizationBC.setOffset(authorizationBC.getOffset() + 6);
                CharChunk authorizationCC = authorization.getCharChunk();
                Base64.decode(authorizationBC, authorizationCC);

                // get username and password from the authorization char chunk.
                int colon = authorizationCC.indexOf(':');
                if (colon < 0) {
                    username = authorizationCC.toString();
                } else {
                    char[] buf = authorizationCC.getBuffer();
                    username = new String(buf, 0, colon);
                    password = new String(buf, colon + 1, authorizationCC.getEnd() - colon - 1);
                }

                authorizationBC.setOffset(authorizationBC.getOffset() - 6);
            }

            principal = context.getRealm().authenticate(username, password);
            if (principal != null) {
                registerWithCallbackHandler(principal, username, password);

                return AuthStatus.SUCCESS;
            }
        }

        // send an "unauthorized" response and an appropriate challenge.
        MessageBytes authenticate = response.getCoyoteResponse().getMimeHeaders().
                addValue(AUTHENTICATE_BYTES, 0, AUTHENTICATE_BYTES.length);

        CharChunk authenticateCC = authenticate.getCharChunk();
        try {
            authenticateCC.append("Basic realm=\"");
            if (config.getRealmName() == null) {
                authenticateCC.append(request.getServerName());
                authenticateCC.append(':');
                authenticateCC.append(Integer.toString(request.getServerPort()));
            } else {
                authenticateCC.append(config.getRealmName());
            }
            authenticateCC.append('\"');
            authenticate.toChars();

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore IOException here (client disconnect)
        }

        return AuthStatus.FAILURE;
    }

}
```

I believe that the following part of the code is the reason we are getting the prompt to enter username and password alert for authentication.

```
MessageBytes authenticate = response.getCoyoteResponse().getMimeHeaders().
                addValue(AUTHENTICATE_BYTES, 0, AUTHENTICATE_BYTES.length);

        CharChunk authenticateCC = authenticate.getCharChunk();
        try {
            authenticateCC.append("Basic realm=\"");
            if (config.getRealmName() == null) {
                authenticateCC.append(request.getServerName());
                authenticateCC.append(':');
                authenticateCC.append(Integer.toString(request.getServerPort()));
            } else {
                authenticateCC.append(config.getRealmName());
            }
            authenticateCC.append('\"');
            authenticate.toChars();

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore IOException here (client disconnect)
        }
```

But if I remove this block, I am getting a good response back (200 response) but the request and response that I am getting back are empty. Please suggest how can i remove this authentication alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom auth module like the following and that served my purpose:

```
public class CustomJaspiAuthModule extends WebServerAuthModule 
{
    private static final String CLASSNAME   = "CustomJaspiAuthModule";
    private static Logger       logger      = Logger.getLogger(CustomJaspiAuthModule.class.getName());

    protected Context context;
    protected String delegatingLoginContextName = null;

    public CustomJaspiAuthModule() { }

    public CustomJaspiAuthModule(String delegatingLoginContextName) 
    {
        super();
        this.delegatingLoginContextName = delegatingLoginContextName;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthStatus secureResponse(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException 
    {
        // do nothing, just return SUCCESS.
        return AuthStatus.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject clientSubject, Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException 
    {
        final String METHOD_NAME = "validateRequest";
        logger.logp(Level.INFO, CLASSNAME, METHOD_NAME, "**IN AUTHENTICATION MODULE**CustomJaspiAuthModule.validateRequest()");

        Request request = (Request) messageInfo.getRequestMessage();
        Response response = (Response) messageInfo.getResponseMessage();

        boolean authenticated = false;
        context = request.getContext();
        Principal principal = context.getRealm().authenticate("*", "*");

        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[] {
                new CallerPrincipalCallback(clientSubject, (Principal) null) };

        if (principal != null) 
        {
            callbacks = new Callback[] { 
                    new CallerPrincipalCallback(clientSubject, principal) };
            authenticated = true;
        } 

        if (authenticated) 
        {
            try 
            {
                callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
            } 
            catch (final Exception e) 
            {
                throw (AuthException) new AuthException().initCause(e);
            }
            return AuthStatus.SUCCESS;
        }

        return AuthStatus.FAILURE;
    }
}
```